# how to reinitialize table edit after infinite scroll for in line edit jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to reinitialize table edit after adding more values to the list by web service.

```
$scope.varietalData = (currPage > 1) ? $scope.varietalData = $scope.varietalData.concat(response.data.data) : response.data.data;
```

Comment: @tgogos can you help?

Comment: As it is now, me and other SO users cannot reproduce your case/problem. Try to edit your question and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).